# Using Entity Framework for SQL Compact Edition 3.5 does not respect mode=exclusive property of connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, database-locking

I am using SQL Server Compact 3.5 edition with Entity Framework and I want to have exclusive lock on the database as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171817.aspx.

However when you pass this in a connection string to Entity Framework it does not respect this at all.

An example of the connection string as following

```
private static readonly string _ConnectionStringFormat =
            @"metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl; provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5; provider connection string='Data Source={0};Mode=Exclusive'";
```

If anyone has come across this issue before and have found out how to resolve this, then please let me know.

Thanks
Aj